# Find only unique named files recursively

Tags: bash, unix, shell

I'm having a problem finding only unique named files over directories and subdirectories. Files must be unique by their name, not md5 sum or content.

I've managed to get list of unique files, but only names, not their location (directory name) with this code. Can't sort properly or use `uniq` if dir name is in the string...

```
find . -type f -name "*" | xargs -I% basename % | sort -u
```

Example of result I got:

```
same_name
some_file
test_file
```

Result expected:

```
./dir1/same_name
./dir1/some_file
./dir3/test_file
```

This would be an example of directory tree, but it can be a lot larger and deeper

```
.
├── dir1
│   ├── same_name
│   └── some_file
├── dir2
│   └── same_name
├── dir3
│   └── test_file
└── same_name
```

Comment: There are 3 files **same_name**: ./same_name ./dir1/same_name ./dir2/same_name, but only one is listed in the example result, so how do you choose the location ?

Comment: Location is not crucial, as long as I get only 1 file of the same name

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like

```
find . -type f -printf "%f:%p\n" | awk -F: '!seen[$1]++ {print $2}'
```

Let find print out the basename for you, and then use awk to print out the pathname only the *first* time the basename is seen.

I used colon as a field separator and newline as the (default) record separator. Both are valid filename characters. This one uses the null character as the record separator (not legal for filenames) and is more robust

```
find . -type f -printf "%f\0%p\0" |
  awk -v RS='\0' '{basename=$0; getline} !seen[basename]++'
```

Comment: I'm really glad to see someone using awk with such elegance.

Comment: Great, this works wonderful. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: voted up! I love the robust version: it should succeed even if there is this directory in the directory tree : **mkdir "$(printf "\1\2\3\4\5\6\7\10\11\12\13\14\15\16\17\20\21\22\23\24\25\26\27\30\31\32\33\34\3‌​5\36\37\40\41\42\43\44\45\46\47testdir" "")"**

Comment: BTW the title mentions **recursively**, but all commands here are going through the directory tree iteratively. Which is efficient for such topic.